# What is the right way to create .env file on remote machine(like AWS instance)?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have a Django project where the settings file refers to a .env file(in root). The .env file contains all the sensitive data like Database password, Debug value. As a security measure, this .env file has been added to .gitignore and wouldn't be uploaded to GIT repository. Now, how do I add this file to the root of a remote host like AWS instance?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of storing and exposing your sensitive data, you can consider [using Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-tutorial.html) to manage your secrets (this is a [sample code in python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-secretsmanager-secrets_manager.py.html) - demonstrates how to retrieve a secret from AWS Secrets Manager).

You can also consider to use a [Python library like this](https://pypi.org/project/django-aws-secrets-manager/) to deal with AWS Secrets Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using AWS Secrets Manager for anything that is sensitive data and just using environment variables for anything else that is environment specific.